# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, class, arguments

I've seen a few of the answers on here regarding my error but its not helped me. I am an absolute noob at classes on python and just started doing this code back in September. Anyway have a look at my code

```
class SimpleCounter():

    def __init__(self, startValue, firstValue):
        firstValue = startValue
        self.count = startValue

    def click(self):
        self.count += 1

    def getCount(self):
        return self.count

    def __str__(self):
        return 'The count is %d ' % (self.count)

    def reset(self):
        self.count += firstValue

a = SimpleCounter(5)
```

and this is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Bilal\Downloads\simplecounter.py", line 26, in <module>
a = SimpleCounter(5)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given
```

Comment: Fyi, your classes should inherit from `object` (google for python new-style classes if you are curious why)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `__init__()` definition requires *both* a `startValue` *and* a `firstValue`. So you'd have to pass both (i.e. `a = SimpleCounter(5, 5)`) to make this code work.

However, I get the impression that there's some deeper confusion at work here:

```
class SimpleCounter():

    def __init__(self, startValue, firstValue):
        firstValue = startValue
        self.count = startValue
```

Why do you store `startValue` to `firstValue` and then throw it away? It seems to me that you mistakenly think that the parameters to `__init__` automatically become attributes of the class. That's not so. You have to assign them explicitly. And since both values are equal to `startValue`, you don't need to pass it to the constructor. You can just assign it to `self.firstValue` like so:

```
class SimpleCounter():

    def __init__(self, startValue):
        self.firstValue = startValue
        self.count = startValue
```

Answer (score 11):

The `__init__()` definition calls for 2 input values, `startValue` and `firstValue`.  You have only supplied one value.

```
def __init__(self, startValue, firstValue):

# Need another param for firstValue
a = SimpleCounter(5)

# Something like
a = SimpleCounter(5, 5)
```

Now, whether you actually need 2 values is a different story.  `startValue` is only used to set the value of `firstValue`, so you could redefine the `__init__()` to use only one:

```
# No need for startValue
def __init__(self, firstValue):
  self.count = firstValue


a = SimpleCounter(5)
```