# class takes exactly three arguments and two are given

Tags: python

I am  trying to make my first game, it is similar to the tron game with the bikes,so far I have created a bike class and several functions to help. However when it runs as below I get an error when I try to declare a Bike object with the velocity, it says that the:

> class Vector takes exactly three arguments and two are given by the
>   what_direction function.

This is a problem for me as I have created a 2x2 matrix to use for changing direction and a function to multiply matrices by vectors. What can I do to fix this error?

```
   import random, math, pygame, sys

    class Vector(object):
        """ |x| = [0]
            |y| = [1] """
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.vec = [ x, y]

    def what_direction():  
        x = random.uniform(0.0, 5.0)
        y = math.sqrt(25-(x**2))
        return x, y

    class Bike(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.position = [random.randint(0, 200), random.randint(0, 200)]
            self.velocity = Vector(what_direction())
            self.score = 0
            self.path_traveled = []
```

Comment: Can you paste the error here?

Comment: Ugh.  I think this is some kind of tuple vs. list thing which I'm not clever enough to figure out.

Comment: One problem is you need : `Vector(*what_direction())`

Comment: I think `what_direction` is returning `x` and `y` as a single value `tuple`. Try "unpacking" it, then passing to `Vector`.

Comment: This might work:  x, y = what_direction()   self.velocity = Vector(x,y)

Comment: No reason to downvote this ppl, it is a perfectly legit question.

Comment: @Houdini Except for the title.

Comment: @Keyser yeah someone should maybe edit that lol

Comment: more or less a duplicate of [TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444992/typeerror-init-takes-exactly-3-arguments-2-given)

Answer (score 9):

Your `what_direction()` function returns a tuple of values, and you're trying to pass that tuple to a function that takes 2 arguments. Python thinks you're passing a single argument (that 2-tuple). You need to unpack the tuple before using it in the expression `Vector(what_direction())`. You can do this yourself:

```
a, b = what_direction()
Vector(a, b)
```

Or you can use the tuple unpacking operator `*`:

```
Vector(*what_direction())
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an asterisk like this:

```
self.velocity = Vector(*what_direction())
```

in order to pass the two components to the `Vector` constructor.  Currently you're passing a single argument which is a tuple with two members.  The asterisk unpacks the tuple, passing its member values as separate arguments to `Vector()`.